# How to schedule a batch script in windows XP?

Tags: batch-file, scheduling

I have a batch script that i want to schedule after every 24 hours. How can i achieve this? the script is running fine when running manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with [AT](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html) command:

```
AT 23:30 /EVERY:m,t,w,th,f,s,su c:\backups\every_day.cmd
```

With [SCHTASKS](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html):

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC DAILY /TN MyDailyBackup /ST 23:00 /TR c:\backup.cmd
```

Comment: just curious: why `weekly`, not `daily`?

Comment: Probably because from the inertia from the AT.Fixed now.

Comment: i want to schedule the script for daily purpose and i m getting an error: `Task Scheduler Error 0x80070005: Access is denied.`